# How to change the reminder/announcement times for `appt`?

Tags: appt

I want to change the reminder/announcement times that `appt` uses.  I know I can do things like:

```
(setq appt-message-warning-time 15)
```

to start the reminders 15 minutes ahead, but how do I change the interval inbetween?  How to have reminders at 15, 10, 5, and 1 minute(s), for example?

Comment: Does the variable `appt-display-interval` help any?  *Interval in minutes at which to display appointment reminders.  Once an appointment becomes due, Emacs displays reminders every `appt-display-interval` minutes.  You probably want to make `appt-message-warning-time` be a multiple of this, so that you get a final message displayed precisely when the appointment is due.*

Comment: @lawlist, I don't think `appt-display-interval` would help for the example in the question, because the intervals are 5, 5, and 4 minutes: that is to say, the intervals are not all identical. Unless I'm mistaken, `appt-display-interval` is only capable of holding one value, which is then used for all intervals.