# Set default timing for reminders/warnings, without identical intervals

Tags: org-mode, appt

*In what follows, I use the terms "warning" and "reminder" synonymously.*

By default, I would like Org to visually warn me of upcoming appointments, at the following times:

- 15 minutes in advance;
- 1 hour in advance;
- 3 hours in advance; and
- 24 hours in advance.

I would also like to be able to manually override this default, for certain appointments, specifying instead a different sequence of reminders.

How can I achieve this?

*N.B. [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7380/8341) is similar. However, my question differs in some significant respects, which is why I think this is not a duplicate question:*

- *That question specifically asks about setting warning intervals for `appt` rather than for `Org mode`. While it's true that the answer to my question* might *involve invoking `appt`, it also might not.*
- *My question asks about setting reminders that occur more than just a few minutes in advance.*
- *My question asks about manually overriding the default intervals.*

Comment: I think the answer is appt. I know the guy who made mu4e made sauron, which is another option

Comment: I would bet my lunch money that it would be easier to modify `appt` then reinvent the wheel.  Absent modification of an existing library, the question would appear to entail the creation of a new library -- rendering it too broad and beyond the scope of what is generally considered to be a reasonable size question/answer.  So, I'm leaning towards a vote to close as being too broad or duplicate.  `org-mode` does not offer this feature and implementing it is not practical within the question/answer format of this site.

Comment: @lawlist point taken, but my question differs in some other respects, which I've now clarified above. I hope it won't be closed as a duplicate, because even if [the other question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7380/8341) were answered satisfactorily, that answer wouldn't necessarily answer all of my question. Alternatively, perhaps the two questions could be merged somehow?

Comment: If a suitable answer is not forthcoming in a reasonable period of time (i.e., the original poster decides what that means), then the original poster may wish to consider making this thread more specific as to creating a new feature for `appt.el` to support up to four (4) notification intervals.  While such a feature request would require an investment of time by anyone interested in answering, it will reduce the nebulous cloud around creating an entirely new feature for `org-mode` in general (effectively disregarding the potential to use the `appt` library that is already built-in to Emacs).